# Mock `TableClient.QueryAsync()` for Unit Test

Tags: azure, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, azure-tableclient

I have the following method that I need to test:

```
public async Task<SomeClass> GetAsync(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
{
    var entities = new List<SomeClass>();
    await foreach (var e in _tableClient.QueryAsync<SomeClass>(x => x.PartitionKey == partitionKey && x.RowKey == rowKey))
    {
        entities.Add(e);
    }
    return entities.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I'd like to setup the `_tableClient.QueryAsync()` (in the moq) to be able to return different result based on the input parameter. This is important to ensure my unit test covers the logic.

My attempt is:

```
var thingsToMock = new List<(string PartitionKey, string RowKey, string Value)>() {
    ("maxCount", "maxCount", "0"),
    ("maxCount", "xyz", "1000"),
    ("maxCount", "abc", "2000")
};
var tableClientMock = new Mock<TableClient>();
foreach (var thingToMock in thingsToMock)
{
    var returnPage = Page<SomeClass>.FromValues(new List<SomeClass>
    {
        new SomeClass{ PartitionKey = thingToMock.PartitionKey, RowKey = thingToMock.RowKey, Value = thingToMock.Value }
    }, null, new Mock<Response>().Object);
    var returnPages = AsyncPageable<SomeClass>.FromPages(new[] { returnPage });
    Expression<Func<SomeClass, bool>> exp = (x) => x.PartitionKey == thingToMock.PartitionKey && x.RowKey == thingToMock.RowKey ? true : false;
    tableClientMock
        .Setup(i => i.QueryAsync<SomeClass>(It.Is<Expression<Func<SomeClass, bool>>>(expression => LambdaExpression.Equals(expression, exp)), null, null, default))
        .Returns(returnPages);
}
```

The issue is that the `_tableClientMock` doesn't seem to return what I expected when I call `GetAsync("maxCount", "abc")`. I'd expect with this call, it would pass in the same parameters to `tableClient.QueryAsync()` method, which in my Mock should return instance of `SomeClass` with value of 2000. But instead, it throw "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

If I change the `tableClientMock` setup for `QueryAsync` to be the following, it *somewhat* works:

```
.Setup(i => i.QueryAsync<SomeClass>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<SomeClass, bool>>>(), null, null, default))
```

But this will not achieve my objective, which is to be able to pass different parameters (`partitionKey` and `rowKey`) to get different result.

I'm using the following NuGet package:

- "Azure.Data.Tables" Version="12.7.1"
- "moq" Version="4.14.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up with the following test. This is lil bit different than the example I provided in the question. But generally it's the same concept on how to mock Azure `TableClient`

The unit test

```cs
// Arrange
var expectedItems = new List<ItemEntity>
{
    new ItemEntity { RowKey = $"0001", PartitionKey = "abc" },
    new ItemEntity { RowKey = $"0002", PartitionKey = "abc" },
}
var tableClient = new Mock<TableClient>();
tableClient
    .Setup(c => c.QueryAsync<ItemEntity>(It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.Is<int>(a => a == 2),
        It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Returns(new MockAsyncPageable<ItemEntity>(expectedItems));
var repo = new Service(tableClient);

// Act
var result = await repo.GetItems("000", 2);

// Assert
result.Should().NotBeNull();
result.Any().Should().BeTrue();
result.Count().Should().Be(2);
tableClient.Verify(c => c.QueryAsync<ItemEntity>(It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.Is<int>(a => a == 2),
    It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
```

The Service's `GetItems` method looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<ItemEntity>> GetItems(string code, int maxPerPage)
{
    var maxPerPage = Math.Clamp(maxPerPage, 1, 1000);
    var filter = $"(RowKey eq '{partialNdc}') and (PartitionKey eq 'abc')";
    return await _tableClient.QueryAsync<ItemEntity>(filter, maxPerPage);
}
```

And lastly the, `MockAsyncPageable<>`

```cs
internal class MockAsyncPageable<T> : AsyncPageable<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _items;

    public MockAsyncPageable(List<T> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    public override IAsyncEnumerable<Page<T>> AsPages(string continuationToken = null, int? pageSizeHint = null)
    {
        var page = Page<T>.FromValues(_items, null, new Mock<Response>().Object);
        return new[] { page }.ToAsyncEnumerable();
    }
}
```

I believe the key is to setup the Mock (`.Setup()`) for the method I'm using, specifically, pass in all the parameters (including optional parameters) even though I don't use it in my `GetItems()` method.

For example, the `.QueryAsync` in my `GetItems()` method used the following method signature of `TableClient`:

```cs
public virtual AsyncPageable<T> QueryAsync<T>(string filter = null, int? maxPerPage = null, IEnumerable<string> select = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class, ITableEntity { }
```

So when I setup the Mock, I pass in all the parameters.